# Restoring iPhoto files from DVD back to the library

Tags: macos, iphoto

I've backed up iPhoto files on to DVD. How can I copy or export them from the DVDs when I open them in iPhoto?

Do I need to import the files back into a new iPhoto Library each time to copy or export?

Answer (score 0):

Try `File` --> `Import To Library`.